# C++ "Reference to overloaded function" error using namespace std

Tags: c++, xcode

I am new to C++, and I keep getting an error saying:

> Reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?

Below is the code that is causing this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    string name;
    string age;
    cout << "Enter your name and age: ";
    cin >> name >> age;
    cout << "Hello, " << name << ", are you " << age << " years old?\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Xcode on Mac OS X Mojave.

I also noticed that if I have only that code, then it works just fine, but when I have multiple files, all of them fail to work.

Can anyone tell me why this is and a solution for it?

Comment: Please read on [mcve]s. As it currently stands, your question is basically unanswerable: We can only guess what your problem could be. [This is a discussion that may also be relevant in your case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385611/how-can-i-add-a-minimal-reproducible-example-if-i-think-ive-already-added-one).

Comment: You need to include `<iostream>` to use `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stdio.h does not define `std::cin` and `std::cout`. That header defines the C functions for input and output, like `printf` and `scanf`. So it is an I/O header, but it's not the one you need.

You need to include `<iostream>` to have `std::cin` and `std::cout`